# Expressions with Python 3.6 'f' strings not compatible with `.format` or `.format_map`

Tags: python

I discovered that `.format_map` and `.format` are not compatible with Python 3.6 `f` strings, in that the native `f` prefix allows complex expressions (such as slices, and function calls), but doing `.format_map` doesn't allow complex expressions, for example:

```
>>> version = '1.13.8.10'                                                                               

>>> f'example-{".".join(version.split(".")[:3])}'                                                          
'example-1.13.8'

>>> 'example-{".".join(version.split(".")[:3])}'.format_map(dict(version=version))                      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '"'

'"'

>>> 'example-{".".join(version.split(".")[:3])}'.format(version=version)                                
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '"'

'"'
```

I really want to be able to expose the full capability of Python `f` strings via a configuration file, where the user supplies a string which may contain non-trivial `{...}` segments which reference the same file and optionally do some basic data manipulation, e.g. within a YAML file I post-process a subset of keys using `.format` so they can reference variables from within the same config file.

This works fine for simple variables, e.g. `{version}` where the YAML file is a dictionary with a `version` key and I pass the dict in as an argument to `.format_map`, but throws `KeyError` with more complicated expressions (as shown above).

There must be a way to get the same functionality as `f` strings... I thought `.format_map` was it... but it doesn't offer complex expressions...

Comment: The full capability of Python `f`-strings includes stuff like `f'{__import__("os").system("install ransomware or something")}'`. It's *much* more than you should expose, even if you think you trust your config files. Way too risky.

Comment: I'm the one writing the config files, I want this functionality, because it saves me 20+ lines of code repeated N times by being able to specify a turing-complete expression within a config file... I just want to know how to emulate `f` strings with a function call - where I pass-in a dictionary of variables, because `.format` and `.format_map` don't allow the extra expressions.

Comment: If you want Turing-complete config files, you could always just write them in Python. That's an actual approach people take.

Comment: That's not the question though... `.format` doesn't support expressions but `f` prefixed strings do... How do I emulate `f` prefixed strings using a run-time function call with a user-supplied dictionary, otherwise I could just call eval(...) and escape the string... but that seems hacky!

Comment: The discomfort you're feeling with `eval` is what you *should* be feeling, since what you're trying to expose *is* the full power of `eval`. If you really want to let config files evaluate arbitrary Python expressions, then the function that evaluates arbitrary Python expressions is a natural tool to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `eval`

```
>>> def format_map_eval(string, mapping):
...     return eval(f'f{string!r}', mapping)
...
>>> version = '1.13.8.10'
>>> some_config_string = 'example-{".".join(version.split(".")[:3])}'
>>> format_map_eval(some_config_string, dict(version=version))
'example-1.13.8'
```

This at least is explicit about you providing this.

The key feature of f-strings is that they evaluate arbitrary expressions inside their formatting brackets. If you want a function call that does this, you are asking for eval.

Now that I think about it, I'm not sure this is safe or portable across implementations because there is no guarantee about the `repr` of `str` as far as I know.

Comment: Superb, thank you. I now have the one and only real-world use of `eval` that I've ever needed to use.